# Loading $scope into another page

Tags: angularjs, scope, routes

I am working on an angular app and I am running into a problem loading $scope into another page.  Here is the code I currently have:

```
function editorCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
   $scope.html = { content: '' };
   $scope.data = {
      name: ''
   }
   $scope.goToDoc = function() {
      $http.get('/doc/' + $scope.data.name).success(function(data) {
         $scope.html.content = JSON.stringify(data.html);
         $location.path('/docs/' + $scope.data.name);
      });
   }
}

// My app config
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .config(function($routeProvider) {
      .when('/editor', {
      controller: 'editorCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/app/partials/editor.html'
  })
  .when('/docs/:name', {
      controller: 'editorCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/app/partials/doc.html'
  })
      ...

// My doc Template
{{ html.content }}

// editor template
<input type="input" ng-model="data.name">
<button ng-click="goToDoc()">GOTO</button>
```

I am trying to do a request to my API and set the $scope.html.content to the returned data.  If I console the $scope.html.content I get the correct value, but it is not updating in my doc template.  How do I get $scope in my editorCtrl to update my doc template?  Or am I going about this in a totally wrong way?

Comment: Did you notice that you wrote `Sscope.html.content` instead of `$scope.html.content`?

Comment: Also, where does the variable `file` comes from? It does not seem to be declared in the context available for `goToDoc`.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo  My bad on the mis-typed $scope.  That is correct in my actual code.  the file var is actually defined in my code, but I was trying to keep it short.  It comes from an input field from my editor page.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo  To be more specific, I have an input in my editor template that has ng-model="data.name" on it and in my editorCtrl I have $scope.data.name.  That is what my file var really is.

Comment: If the code that post to ask a question is not sensible we cannot help you, because we cannot determine if that is what is wrong or if there is something else.

Comment: I updated the code to give you all the relavent data.  I know that the $scope is working because I consoled out the data.html that was returned from the $http call.  I am having trouble figuring out why it is not updating in my doc template.  When I click the GOTO button, it is correctly going to the /docs/:name page, but the data is not being displayed.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo  Sorry about the confusion.  I edited my code to have everything you need and fixed the errors.  This is the first time I have asked a question on here, so I'm sorry.  I'll do better next time.